# Split a string into an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string in C#. It's blank at the beginning, but eventually it will become something like

```
public string info12 = "0, 50, 120, 10";
```

One of you might be thinking, eh? Isn't than an integer array? Well it needs to stay a string for the time being, it must be a string.

How can I convert this string into an string array (Variable info13) so I can eventually reference it into more variables.

```
info 14 = info13[0];
info 15 = info13[1];
```

PLEASE NOTE: This is not a duplicate question. If you read the whole thing, I clearly stated that I have an array of strings not integers.

Comment: You can simply call the .Split('?,') method, so simple!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are a few options:

**1.** String.Split with char and String.Trim

Use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then trim the results to remove extra spaces.

```
public string[] info13 = info12.Split(',').Select(str => str.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Remember that `Select` needs [`using System.Linq;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

**2.** String.Split with char array

No need for trim, although this method is not my favorite

```
public string[] info13 = info12.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

**3.** Regex

```
public string[] info13 = Regex.Split(info12, ", ");
```

Which requires [`using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT:** Because you no longer need to worry about spaces, you can simply do:

```
public string[] info13 = info12.Split(',');
```

Which will return a string array of the split items.

Comment: My bad, there shouldn't be any spaces. But I do get this error

a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property gui.info12

Comment: You cannot access something that is not static, from a static method. Try making `info12` static, provided that their is only one instance of it.

Comment: It's not static. The script changes the variable info 12 towards the beginning of the script.

Comment: `static` does not mean `const`, it can still be changed. You are trying to reference a non static object from a static method.

Comment: I changed info 12 to a static string. Now it says System.Array does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument.

Comment: As I said, you need to include System.Linq with `using System.Linq;` Make sure you have System.Xml.Linq in your references as well.

Comment: That should do for now. Thank You @Cyral